# Looking for a full featured C/C++ UV Mesh Unwrapper

Tags: c++, textures, 3d-meshes, uv-mapping

My first question!
Is there an open source C++/C piece of code easy to integrate to solve the UV Unwrapping of arbitrary meshes out there ?
I would like to use it to build a light mapper or similar stuff.
Of course i'm looking for non-naive solutions but something that solves the issue with maximum exploiting of texture surface and so on..

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Well, i'd probably start by taking a look at the blender unwrapping code, since blender is some open souce flavor; it appears to start here:

https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/source/blender/editors/uvedit/uvedit_unwrap_ops.c

I know the have a "pack lightmaps" command in their uv unwrap menu, but I wasn't able to locate it in unknown code in a short time on my phone :3

Good luck.